# Is it possible to prohibit the translation of the name of the educational institution on my site into another language?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a site for a training center, the name of the training center is in English, if the site is translated to another language, the appearance of the training center name is changing and it is breaking the site design, so I only have o 'tuition center name site user When enabling translation on the site, I want to prohibit the translation of only one word, but I don't know how to do it

Comment: How do you translate that site? How is this problem related to Javascript, HTML, or CSS?

Comment: Use an image perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Google adding translate="no" should prevent translation.

```
Welcome to <span translate="no">Company XXXXXX</span> website.
```